# Error at the time of running Phpunit tests in Symfony

Tags: phpunit, symfony-1.4

I am trying to run this command `./symfony phpunit:test-unit` for my symfony project but I am getting following error:

> Warning: require_once(Phactory/lib/Phactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/shivalibari/repos/hpadvise/advisestream/test/phpunit/bootstrap/unit.php on line 34

So can anybody tell me what I am missing or whats wrong?

Comment: Did you check that "Phactory/lib/Phactory.php" is reachable with your include path?

Comment: Could you show us your `advisestream/test/phpunit/bootstrap/unit.php` file?